# Which body position causes the least amount of negative acceleration?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, forces, collision, biophysics, free-fall

Let's say you are in the air 500 meters above flat land and you have no parachute. Which pose - forming a sphere or spreading all extremities to make yourself as wide as possible or other - is the most appropriate to cause the highest likelihood of survival?

1. in the air
2. right before impact

In other words: which body position causes the least amount of negative acceleration in this context?

PS: As a side-question: Which body position enables you to control the direction of flight to control your angle of impact and make it as flat as possible?

My take: In the air make yourself as wide as possible and control direction by weight displacement. Right before impact, form a sphere when having a flat angle of impact and let rolling take care of the change of kinetic energy into heat and potential energy.

Comment: My take: you're going to splat no matter what.  I don't really think you can control your angle of impact much and curling your body into a ball isn't going to help or make you roll because at that velocity you're pretty much a sponge of meat saturated with water.

Comment: My take: don't go jumping out of an airplane without either a parachute or a wingsuit because it will end **very** badly for you otherwise.

Comment: Correct, which is why it is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @KyleKanos Which is why you should've kept your comment to yourself.

Comment: Debatable. Besides, your question isn't really answerable. You really think someone could *roll* after curling up in a ball? I mean, you do realize that you'd be traveling at terminal velocity of roughly 130 mph? You don't *roll*, you go **splat**.

Comment: And it is not even the question. The question is about the highest likelihood of survival. And this question is very well answerable - provided of course that you have the knowledge, which I doubt about you two when I read "you go splat".

Comment: Actually, an easy inference from the comments given: you have a 0% chance of surviving regardless of posture because you'd go from ~130 mph to 0 mph in less than a second (force of a few hundred thousand Newtons).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about optimizing a complex system where all realistic outcomes are suboptimal (death).

Comment: Your changes of survival depend more on what happens on the ground (i.e. grassland, thicket, trees, etc) reduced velocity on impact. That is your best change of survival.

Comment: Apparently approximately 13 people have survived just such a scenario. Check out these articles [here](http://www.popularmechanics.com/outdoors/survival/stories/how-a-16-year-old-girl-could-have-survived-a-3500-foot-free-fall-16437891) and [here](http://www.popularmechanics.com/technology/aviation/safety/4344036).

Comment: @OSE Very interesting. Therefore my approach is not so bad after all.